# CiviCRM Converting HTML tag to Entity

Tags: drupal, issues, civicrm-entity, html

we're having an issue with newsletters being sent out with broken images due to the opening and closing tags being converted to HTML entities.

e.g.
`<img src="foo.jpg" />` is sent out as: `&lt; img src="foo.jpg" /&gt;`

We don't have control over the CiviCRM install however it's running on Drupal 7.

I'm wondering if this is a simple fix I could instruct a client on doing themselves or if it will require more work.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm assuming you're using the default mailing Ux, not mosaico*

The default editor is wysiwyg, if you want to put html tags, click on the view source icon, and paste the html code you want.

You can switch back to wysiwyg to see the result.

As for the images, be aware that quite a few recipients aren't going to display the image (for privacy reasons), so you should consider putting an alt text and dimensions (width and height) on your img tag

Comment: Thanks for your response! The newsletter is actually generated via another CMS and sent out through Civi on Drupal. All images have alt tags and height/width set on them. The code is generated perfectly fine until it gets passed through Civi and then seemingly random images get their tags converted to entities. Is it possible this is an SMTP service issue?

Comment: Hi, unless you have a weird smtp server, it shouldn't touch the content at all. What do you mean by generating via another CMS? are you using civicrm api or copy/pasting?